# How to get a loading gif to work while running a command

Tags: python, bash, kivy, python-multithreading, animated-gif

I am trying to get a gif of a loading circle to play while I run another python script.

When I click a button I get a popup that has a loading gif, in the background I want to run a python script while this gif loads. Once the script is complete the popup closes.

So far all of this works except the gif freezes once the other python script starts running.

I have tried using `os.system()`, `subprocess.run()` and the controversial `subprocess.Popen()`. I have also tried using the threading and multiprocessing python modules.

Threading seems to be the way to go however I still get the same result (the gif freezing once I start running the other python script).

I am aware that there are many other similar questions out there, however I can assure you I have read them all and tried their solutions, but for some reason they are not working for me. I have been working on this for days and cannot find a solution so any help would be greatly appreciated.

For an overall picture, I am writing a python3.7 application using kivy to create a GUI. I am running this application on a Raspberry Pi 4.

The following is are snippets of my current, relevant code:
(The "..." indicate where other irrelevant code is)

main.py

```
class SetttingsWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SettingsWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check, 1)

    def check(self, dt):
        global wset
        if wset:
            self.start_thread()
        else:
            pass

    def start_thread(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.connect)
        t.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        t.join()

    def connect(self):
        global wset
        os.system('sudo python /home/pi/app/connect.py')
        wset = False
        loadingPopup.dissmiss()

    def set(self):
        Popup.open()


class PopUp(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PopUp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change(self):
        global wset
        if ... :
            PopUp.dismiss()
        else:
            ...
            PopUp.dissmiss()
            wset = True

    def setLoad(self):
        loadingPopup.open()


class LoadingPopUp(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

main.kv

```
<SettingsWindow>
    ...
    Button:
        text: "Setup"
        on_release:
            root.set()
    ...
...
<PopUp>
    ...
    Button:
        text: "Set"
        on_release:
            root.change()
            root.setLoad()
    ...
...
<LoadingPopUp>
    Image:
        source: "loading.gif"
        anim_delay: 0.05
        keep_data: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `check()` method will be run in the main thread (as called by `Clock.schedule_interval`). That method calls `start_thread`, which starts a new thread to run your `connect` method. All that is fine, but then you call `t.join()`, which stops the main thread until your `connect` method completes. While waiting for the `connect` thread to complete, your GUI will stop completely. I suggest removing the lines:

```
    time.sleep(1)
    t.join()
```

to allow the GUI to operate.

Comment: Thank you John,  that makes my gif work (slowly I may add but I assume that's down to CPU more than anything). However, now my script/command runs repeatedly for a good few minutes. I cannot let it do this. Any suggestions for how to stop this? as my `t.join` was doing that before.

Comment: The `gif` speed is set by the `anim_delay` attribute of the `Image`. So, setting `anim_delay` to 0.1, should produce 10fps, 0.05 should produce 20fps, etc. Setting `anim_delay` to -1 should stop the animation.

Comment: Thanks John, I have anim_delay set. Any suggestions on how to fix my problem of my script/command running repeatedly?

Comment: At the end of your `connect()` method you can use `Clock.schedule_once()` to call a method that sets `anim_delay` to -1 and/or dismisses the Popup. The `Clock.schedule_once()` ensures that the called method runs on the main thread (as is required for anything that modifies the GUI).

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining myself well, sorry. I have a line of code to close my pop up, however my code is not getting to that line because it just runs the previous line over and over  `os.system('sudo python /home/pi/connect.py)`. This is why I had the line `t.join()` as this killed the thread and stop this line from repeating. But since I took this line out, the `os.system` line seems to run in an almost infinite loop. I think it runs for about a minute and then perhaps timesout.

Comment: What happens if you move the `wset=False` before the `os.system()` call?

Comment: Oh wow, so simple. Just needed a fresh pair of eyes. That worked, thank you for all your help John.